# Error composing koa async function middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, koa, koa2

I am using `koa-compose` to put together middleware as suggested in the [guide](https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/v2.x/docs/guide.md). I import `koa-compose` as `kompose`.

I have the following code:

```
const home = async function home (ctx,next) {
  if(ctx.path === '/') {
    ctx.body = 'Hello World!'
  } else {
    await next()
  }
}

const random = async function random (ctx,next) {
  console.log(ctx)
  if(ctx.path === '/random') {
    console.log('Inside random function')
    ctx.body = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
  } else {
    await next()
  }
}

const backwards = async function backwards (ctx,next) {
  if(ctx.path === '/backwards') {
    ctx.body = 'sdrawkcab'
  } else {
    await next()
  }
}

const pi = async function pi (ctx,next) {
  if(ctx.path === '/pi') {
    ctx.body = String(Math.PI)
  } else {
    await next()
  }
}

const body2 = kompose([random,backwards,pi,home])
```

I use it as the last middleware in the chain:

```
app.use(responseTime())
app.use(logger())
app.use(body2)
app.listen(3000)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
      at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vamsi/Do/koa-tutorial/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:28:19)
      at undefined.next (native)
      at onFulfilled (/home/vamsi/Do/koa-tutorial/node_modules/co/index.js:65:19)
      at /home/vamsi/Do/koa-tutorial/node_modules/co/index.js:54:5
      at new Promise (/home/vamsi/.nvm/v6.2.0/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.promise.js:191:7)
      at Object.co (/home/vamsi/Do/koa-tutorial/node_modules/co/index.js:50:10)
      at converted (/home/vamsi/Do/koa-tutorial/node_modules/koa-convert/index.js:17:15)
      at dispatch (/home/vamsi/Do/koa-tutorial/node_modules/koa/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:43:32)
      at next (/home/vamsi/Do/koa-tutorial/node_modules/koa/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:44:18)
      at _callee7$ (index.js:72:11)
```

The full code is [on github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429668/error-composing-koa-async-function-middleware). You can replace `body()` with `body2` in the code there.

## UPDATE:

After doing a bit of additional logging, it says:

```
 TypeError: next is not a function
       at Object._callee3$ (index.js:29:11)
       at tryCatch (/home/vamsi/.nvm/v6.2.0/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:62:40)
       at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/home/vamsi/.nvm/v6.2.0/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:336:22)
       at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/home/vamsi/.nvm/v6.2.0/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:95:21)
       at step (index.js:3:1)
       at index.js:3:1
       at new Promise (/home/vamsi/.nvm/v6.2.0/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.promise.js:191:7)
       at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:3:1)
       at Object.backwards (index.js:25:7)
       at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vamsi/Do/koa-tutorial/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:25:28),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a generator-based `koa-compose` for Koa 2, that won't work. You need `koa-compose@3.x` install it with:

```
npm install -S koa-compose@next
```